# concatenate a cartesian string by a group

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use a combination of Double Metaphone and other string comparison functions. Double Metaphone gives you 2 coded values for every name. 
To do this I have taken the full names and split them into seperate rows for each part of the name (FirstName, MiddleName etc..., LastName) and encoded them. Now I want to combine them back into a single string for each possible combination to use another comparison function.

```
create table #MADblMetCombined
(
    OriginID int,
    DisplayName nvarchar(100),
    NamePartId int,
    DblMetC nvarchar(10)
)


insert into #MADblMetCombined values (3,'Jan Wijnants',1,'JN')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (3,'Jan Wijnants',1,'AN')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (3,'Jan Wijnants',2,'FJNNT')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (3,'Jan Wijnants',2,'AJNNT')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',1,'JN')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',1,'AN')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',2,'FRNKK')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',2,'ARNKK')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',3,'AJNNT')
insert into #MADblMetCombined values (19,'Johnny Warangkula Wijnants',3,'FJNNT')
```

I will end up with a table like:

[image]

Now I want a Cartesian product of each the DblMetC grouped by (originid, namePartId). It would look like:

[image]
How do I get that last table?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a Cartesian would mean you'd also have the inverse values as well...

```
select distinct 
    x.OriginID
    ,x.DblMetC + ' ' + y.DblMetC 
from #MADblMetCombined x
left join #MADblMetCombined y on 
y.NamePartId != x.NamePartId and x.OriginID = y.OriginID
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----------+------------------+
| OriginID | (No column name) |
+----------+------------------+
|        3 | AJNNT AN         |
|        3 | AJNNT JN         |
|        3 | AN AJNNT         |
|        3 | AN FJNNT         |
|        3 | FJNNT AN         |
|        3 | FJNNT JN         |
|        3 | JN AJNNT         |
|        3 | JN FJNNT         |
|       19 | AJNNT AN         |
|       19 | AJNNT ARNKK      |
|       19 | AJNNT FRNKK      |
|       19 | AJNNT JN         |
|       19 | AN AJNNT         |
|       19 | AN ARNKK         |
|       19 | AN FJNNT         |
|       19 | AN FRNKK         |
|       19 | ARNKK AJNNT      |
|       19 | ARNKK AN         |
|       19 | ARNKK FJNNT      |
|       19 | ARNKK JN         |
|       19 | FJNNT AN         |
|       19 | FJNNT ARNKK      |
|       19 | FJNNT FRNKK      |
|       19 | FJNNT JN         |
|       19 | FRNKK AJNNT      |
|       19 | FRNKK AN         |
|       19 | FRNKK FJNNT      |
|       19 | FRNKK JN         |
|       19 | JN AJNNT         |
|       19 | JN ARNKK         |
|       19 | JN FJNNT         |
|       19 | JN FRNKK         |
+----------+------------------+
```

To get what you want, you'd need something *like* the below, which isn't a true Cartesian product:

```
select
    x.OriginID
    ,coalesce(x.DblMetC + ' ' + y.DblMetC  + ' ' + z.DblMetC,x.DblMetC + ' ' + y.DblMetC,x.DblMetC)
from #MADblMetCombined x
inner join #MADblMetCombined y on 
y.NamePartId = x.NamePartId +1 and x.OriginID = y.OriginID and y.NamePartId = 2
left join #MADblMetCombined z on 
z.NamePartId = x.NamePartId + 2 and z.OriginID = x.OriginID and z.NamePartId = 3
```

Comment: I tried an approach like that, but it doesn't give me the full name that I am looking for (FirstName + MiddleName + LastName)

Comment: Oh isee what you are trying to do... one sec for an edit

Comment: I was thinking of using some sort "for xml path" solution, but couldn't figure out how to do the grouping.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but I have some cases with multiple middle names. I could theoretically just add more left joins but was really hoping for something more dynamic like some kind of "for xml path" solution. I am going to wait to see if anyone has any more ideas before implementing this solution.

Comment: For xml path wouldn't give you the Cartesian product you want without getting real ugly. And it's complicated and hard to debug. Multiple middle names wouldn't matter unless your NamePartId continues to increase. It looks like 2 can be middle or last name in your sample data. This makes yoru data very ugly.